Computing the charge of an extremal black hole with no angular momentum and a given mass
I've had a difficult time finding convenient equations or tools for deriving extremal (without angular momentum) blackholes' necessary charge/mass for a given mass/charge. Specifically:

For a given mass (eg 1kg) what is the maximal charge (eg in elementary charges) for an extremal black hole without angular momentum?

Conversely, for an extremal black hole of a given charge and without angular momentum, what is the minimal mass?

I'd also be interested in computing both of these threshold values for a given mass and schwarzchild evaporation temperature (which is 0 for extremal black holes, if I understand correctly).


For context, I'm curious about some of the engineering practicalities concerning man-made extremal blackholes. Since it'd be difficult to get exactly the right charge:mass ratio in the instant such a black hole is formed, I'm guessing most man-made black-holes would be sub-extremal both during formation and once "completed", so I want to understand what kind of masses, charges, and temperature ranges (and their error tolerances) would be involved.

To give back to the community, once there are workable formulas for calculating these threshold values I'm happy to put a simple calculator for this up on a web site so that in the future people interested in these values can simply plug in their parameters and go. I tried using the calculator at https://space.geometrian.com/calcs/black-hole-params.php but it unfortunately does not properly handle schwarzchild evaporation time/temp properly IIUC, which makes me skeptical of its calculations for mass/charge at extremal fraction=1.


Fred Weitendorf asked: "For a given mass (eg 1kg) what is the maximal charge (eg in elementary charges) for an extremal black hole without angular momentum?"

For an extremal Reissner Nordström black hole set
$$\rm \frac{Q}{M} \sqrt{\frac{K}{G}}=1$$
where $\rm Q$ is the charge, $\rm M=E/c^2$ is the total energy equivalent, $\rm K$ is the Coulomb constant and $\rm G$ the gravitational constant.
For a black hole of $\rm M=1 \ kg$ this gives $\rm Q\approx8.6 \cdot 10^{-11} \ C$ and an irreducible mass of $\rm m=M/2$ (in that case the mass energy and the electric field energy have equal magnitude).
